# Toggle classes between two different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle between two classes on two anchor tags. When I click on the non-bold link, I want it to go bold, and then the other go to normal. However I don't really know how to go about it.

I've tried a few approaches:

```js
$(".link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
      }
  });
```

```css
.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="two-links">
  <span>Filter By:</span>
  <a class="link selected" href="#">Link1</a>
  <a class="link" href="#">Link2<a>
</div>
```

Here, I add and remove based on the target and check if that class is present but it doesn't handle the other non-clicked anchor - I need to click that to remove the bolding when it needs to happen automatically.

I then mess around `toggleClass()`:

```js
 $(".link").click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
 });
```

```css
.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="two-links">
      <span>Filter By:</span>
      <a class="link selected" href="#">Link1</a>
      <a class="link" href="#">Link2</a>
    </div>
```

Which is definitely a step closer but I don't understand how to establish a relationship with `toggleClass()` and more than one element.

Am I going about this the right way or is there something better?

Comment: Remove class `selected` from `$(".link")` then add class `selected` to `$(this)` aka clicked item. There is no need to check for selected class in this case. I am also assuming you don't want the bold link to go normal when clicked on. I could post an answer if you can confirm my assumptions are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this. You can use [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method.

```js
$(".link").click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    $(this).siblings('a').toggleClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="two-links">
  <span>Filter By:</span>
  <a class="link selected" href="#">Link1</a>
  <a class="link" href="#">Link2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: probably want to only removeClass on siblings.

Comment: This is super close, but it's affecting the `<span>` tag. I think I need to pass a specific argument into `siblings()` to prevent that. Thanks

Comment: @kawnah can add a selector  like `siblings('a')` and won't affect span

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you. I will adjust my answer.

Comment: @kawnah I've adjusted my answer.

Comment: Is the bold link supposed to go normal when you click on it?

Comment: There should be an if statement checking if the link has the class of selected first otherwise if you click on the same link twice the selected class will be added to all of the other sibling elements

Comment: @SteveK I ended up needing to do that, since you would click on the unselected link and it would toggle back.

Comment: @kawnah for a simpler solution refer to my early comment on your post or my answer for sample code

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is the right one, but something that should be added:

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
    var isSelected = $(this).hasClass("selected");
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!isSelected) {
      $(this).toggleClass("selected");
      $(this).siblings('a').toggleClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Essentially, only perform the toggle action if what you're clicking on is NOT the selected element.

Comment: So essentially nothing happens if you clicked on the selected element

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".link").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Remove selected class from all `.link` then add it to the clicked element. This will work for more than 2 links and it is simpler. There is no need to check for selected class or get siblings.